# Can you play Plunder mode solo?

Tags: call-of-duty-warzone

How do you play plunder mode solo? I've seen videos of people playing plunder without a squad. Is that an older option that's no longer in there? I don't see how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

On the main "Play" tab where you select Battle Royale or Plunder, there is an option you can set called "Squad Fill". If you turn that option off, it will not fill your squad and you can play on your own like that.